# Two subgroups of order $2$ gives a subgroup of order $4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Why is it the case that abelian group that contains a pair of cyclic subgroups of order 2 must contain a subgroup of order 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the pair be $\{e,a\}$ and $\{e,b\}$. Then $\{e,a,b,ab\}$ is the order $4$ subgroup you want. It is a subgroup because $G$ is abelian and $bab=abb=ae=a$ and $aba=b$ similarly.